# Can Someone Tell me if This Sentence is a Pun?

Tags: puns

My friend and I are walking along a nude beach. There is an exposed man directly in front of us.  My friend asks me what time it is. My response is "It's 12 o'**cock**."

Pun or bad joke?

Comment: Why can't it be both? [A hun is the lowest form of roomer](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vs_bQiT4EWgC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=a+hun+is+the+lowest+form+of+roomer&source=bl&ots=4kcveaHlaF&sig=lvp_vXVB8OGJqZZ4_jCK8Pflt1k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CAorU-32I6Hh0gG954GABg&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=a%20hun%20is%20the%20lowest%20form%20of%20roomer&f=false).

Comment: I'd go with just a bad joke.  I don't think the two words sound similar /enough/ to make it as a pun.

Comment: Look up _Freudian slip_.

Comment: I thought it was a sun-dial joke, until I realized that the word after "12" wasn't "o'clock."

Answer (score 2):

It is both a pun and a bad joke.  (Many puns are both.)

This would be an example of a homophonic [pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun), which uses two words that sound similar ([homophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone)), substituting one for the other.

Comment: Is a 'homophonic pun' also a pun in this situation at the nude beach? :)